# I'm trying to code hangman in python. How do I replace a "_" with the letter guessed?

Tags: python, replace

Yesterday I saw a solution on this website and manage to make it work. However, I tried fixing up a few things in the code and, despite running, the code does not replace the blank space with the letter anymore. I have tried other solutions but nothing seems to make it work.
I have also seen another solution that worked but, if the word had more than one of the guessed letter, it would only replace the first one.

This is my code

```
import random

possible_words = ["test"]

word = random.choice(possible_words)

board = list("_" * len(word))
lives = 7
guessed_letters = []

print("You're playing hangman and you have 7 lives. \n")

print(*board)

while "_" in board and lives >= 1:
    guess = input("Enter a character to guess: ").lower()
    if len(guess) == 1:
        if guess in word:
            if guess in guessed_letters:
                print("You have already guessed the letter \n", guess)

            else:
                print(guess, "is in the word! \n")
                guessed_letters.append(guess)
                for i, x in enumerate(word):
                    if x is guess:
                        board[i] = guess

        elif guess not in word:
            if guess in guessed_letters:
                print("You have already guessed the letter", guess, "\n")
                continue
            elif guess not in guessed_letters:
                print(guess, "is not in the word.")
                guessed_letters.append(guess)
                lives -= 1
                print("You have", lives, "lives left.\n")
    else:
        print("Input error. Enter a valid character. \n")
print(*board)
```

Comment: `x is guess` looks suspicious.  If you use `x == guess` does that fix it?

Comment: the code looks like it should work, except `print(*board)` should probably be inside the loop so the user sees that update as they make guesses. What specific problems are you having?

Comment: @RobinZigmond In the actual code I have print(*board) is actually inside the loop but when I copied my code to stack overflow I forgot to add it. So, when I edited my post I didn't quite know how to put it inside the loop